Xbox controller support
This is my literal first day with any linux ever im useing 24.04 and trying to get all my stuff up and working but steam and linux wont detect either of my xbox one or xbox 360 controllers (all wired) any help is appreciated

This may be helpful https://hatchjs.com/xbox-series-x-controller-ubuntu/
